# Travis CI Build failure with JDK 1.8.60, Maven 3.1.1 and maven-plugin-plugin

Tags: java, maven, travis-ci

I keep getting a build failure on this [pull request](https://github.com/fbiville/liquigraph/pull/91).
Even if I downgrade `maven-plugin-plugin` to 3.2 or upgrade to the latest 3.4, I keep getting this [error](https://travis-ci.org/fbiville/liquigraph/jobs/139888334#L390):

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.3:helpmojo (help-goal) on project liquigraph-maven-plugin: Error extracting plugin descriptor: 'Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream' -> [Help 1]
```

It seems to be OS-dependent (my laptop as aligned to the same Maven version and JDK, no luck).

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, hope anyone of them would solve your build issue. Try one step at a time and do a build

1) Delete the org.apache.maven.plugins from (~/.m2/repository)

2) Check for the jar which is causing the failure, if it is there in the (~/.m2/repository) then run `mvn clean install -o` "o" is for offline mode.

3) Try hitting the url of the jar which is failing to download thru browser, if it works then download the jar and paste it in the respective package under (~/.m2/repository) then run a build in offline mode.

4) `mvn clean install -e` This will give clean stack trace.

If still problem exists post the stack trace here by running the command given in step 4

Comment: The build worker is provisioned by Travis CI, so I cannot directly intervene there. I cannot reproduce it locally. I guess I can disable Travis cache and see how it goes.

Comment: Disabling cache did the trick! Not ideal, but better than no solution :o)